# Batch delete operation procedure not working

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which looks like following:

```
alter procedure [dbo].[zsp_deleteEndedItems]
(
@ItemIDList nvarchar(max)
)
as
delete from 
SearchedUserItems
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.SplitStringProduction(@ItemIDList,',') S1 WHERE ItemID=S1.val)
```

The parameter IDList is passed like following:

```
124125125,125125125...etc etc
```

And the split string function look like following:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitStringProduction]
(
  @string nvarchar(max),
  @delimiter nvarchar(5)
) RETURNS @t TABLE
(
  val nvarchar(500)
)
AS
BEGIN
  declare @xml xml
  set @xml = N'<root><r>' + replace(@string,@delimiter,'</r><r>') + '</r></root>'

  insert into @t(val)
  select 
    r.value('.','varchar(500)') as item
  from @xml.nodes('//root/r') as records(r)

  RETURN
END
```

This is supposed to delete all items from table "SearcheduserItems" under the IDs:

```
124125125 and 125125125
```

But for some reason after I do a select to check it out:

```
select * from SearchedUserItems
where itemid in('124125125','125125125')
```

The records are still there...

What am I doing wrong here? Can someone help me out?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend rewriting that multiline TVF to an inline TVF; you'll very likely to get a performance benefit from doing so.

Comment: Which SQL Server version are you targetting? Every supported version and even the unsupported ones (2005-2008 R2) has far better options. If you used C# it's even easier. You don't gain anything by using a stored procedure. If you want to delete a lot of rows execute a plain old SQL string that contains `delete TargetTable where ID in (......)` and pass the IDs in there. You can use a micro ORM like Dapper to do it for you too, eg `connection.Execute("delete table X where ID in (@ids)", new {ids=thatIdList});`. Full ORM like EF will generate a similar query when you delete multiple entities

Comment: I strongly recommend stop fiddling about with delimited strings and pass the ids to be deleted from c# to SQL Server using a table valued parameter.

Comment: In SQL only solutions, you can pass a table-valued parameter and join with it. If you have a *lot* of entries though, it's faster to write them to an indexed temporary table and join with that. Inserting thousands of IDs can be done using eg `SqlBulkInsert` quickly

Comment: @Larnu can you show me an example of that please? =)

Comment: Do you mean of an iTVF @User987?

Comment: @User987 why are you trying to split strings in the first place? That's the slowest and most complex way possible. Just write a simple DELETE or let an ORM do it for you. Or use a table-valued parameter. Why *split* when you can pass a list of IDs?

Comment: @Larnu yes that one :)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos how would I do that ?

Comment: @User987 besides, consider the limitations. A varchar parameter can only hold up to 8000 characters which is *less* than 1000 IDs if they have more than 8 digits. An `IN` clause though can handle 1000 items and performs very fast

Comment: What is the connection string?  This usually occurs because you have two instances of the database.  Do a search for the mdf file and see if you have more than one.  Adding a "USE" statement to your Command Text may be needed if you have more than one database in the server.  The Default Database in the connection string may need to be changed (or add the USE).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm up for that version as well , could you show me an example of that ? :)

Comment: @jdweng I've checked the web config... The default DB is same as the target one on which i'm trying to perform the operation =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, a different option would be to use a table type parameter. This makes a couple of assumptions (some commented), however, should get you on the right path:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.IDList AS TABLE (ItemID int NOT NULL); --Assumed int datatype;
GO

ALTER PROC dbo.zsp_deleteEndedItems @ItemIDList dbo.IDList READONLY AS

    DELETE SUI
    FROM dbo.SearchedUserItems SUI
         JOIN @ItemIDList IDL ON SUI.ItemID = IDL.ItemID;
GO

--Example of usage

DECLARE @ItemList dbo.IDList;

INSERT INTO @ItemList
VALUES(123456),(123457),(123458);

EXEC dbo.zsp_deleteEndedItems @ItemList;

GO
```

In regards to the question of an inline table value function, one such example is the below, which I quickly wrote up, that provides a tally table of the next 1000 numbers:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.NextThousand (@Start int)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN

    WITH N AS(
        SELECT N
        FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL)) N(N)
    )
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 + @Start AS I
    FROM N N1 --10
         CROSS JOIN N N2 --100
         CROSS JOIN N N3; --1,000
GO
```

The important thing about an iTVF is that it has only one statement, and that is the `RETURN` statement. Declaring the table as a return type variable, inserting data into it, and returning that variable turns it into a multi-line TVF; which perform far slower.

Comment: Hey ! Thanks for the quick reply ! How would I actually call this method from C# ?

Comment: @User987 The documentation tells you all you need to know: [Table-Valued Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters)